# Checkout email domain validation

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, validation

In magento checkout, if the customer's **email domain** is **not valid**, the order is normally completed, using `email.example.com` as custome email.

I have found that there's a list of allowed email domains in `lib/Zend/Validate/Hostname.php` file, but adding new domains on that list is not a solution. Shouldn't magento prevent orders using non-valid email domains? Or just display a warning in checkout page, informing customer about his email? Isn't this part of email validation?

I'd like to add a warning in checkout page, in case the email domain is not valid. How can I do that?

---

### **SOLUTION POSTED BELOW**

In file `js/prototype/validation.js` file, replace `['validate-email']` code with the following:

```
['validate-email', 'Please enter a valid email address. For example johndoe@domain.com.', function (v) {
    return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /^([a-z0-9,!\#\$%&'\*\+\/=\?\^_`\{\|\}~-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z0-9,!\#\$%&'\*\+\/=\?\^_`\{\|\}~-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*@([a-z0-9-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z0-9-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*\.((abogado|ac|academy|accountants|active|actor|ad|ae|aero|af|ag|agency|ai|airforce|al|allfinanz|alsace|am|an|android|ao|aq|ar|archi|army|arpa|as|asia|associates|at|attorney|au|auction|audio|autos|aw|ax|axa|az|ba|band|bar|bargains|bayern|bb|bd|be|beer|berlin|best|bf|bg|bh|bi|bid|bike|bio|biz|bj|black|blackfriday|bloomberg|blue|bm|bmw|bn|bnpparibas|bo|boo|boutique|br|brussels|bs|bt|budapest|build|builders|business|buzz|bv|bw|by|bz|bzh|ca|cab|cal|camera|camp|cacerresearch|capetown|capital|caravan|cards|care|career|careers|casa|cash|cat|catering|cc|cd|center|ceo|cern|cf|cg|ch|channel|cheap|christmas|chrome|church|ci|citic|city|ck|cl|claims|cleaning|click|clinic|clothing|club|cm|cn|co|coah|codes|coffee|college|cologne|com|community|company|computer|condos|construction|consulting|ontractors|cooking|cool|coop|country|cr|credit|creditcard|cricket|crs|cruises|cu|cuisinella|cv|cw|cx|cy|cymru|cz|dad|dance|dating|day|de|deals|degree|delivery|democrat|dental|dentist|desi|diamonds|diet|digital|direct|directory|discount|dj|dk|dm|dnp|do|domains|durban|dvag|dz|eat|ec|edu|education|ee|eg|email|emerck|energy|engineer|engineering|enterprises|equipment|er|es|esq|estate|et|eu|eus|events|everbank|exchange|expert|exposed|fail|farm|feedback|fi|finance|financial|firmdale|fish|fishing|fitness|fj|fk|flights|florist|flsmidth|fly|fm|fo|foo|forsale|foundation|fr|frl|frogans|fund|furniture|ftbol|ga|gal|gallery|gb|gbiz|gd|ge|gent|gf|gg|gh|gi|gift|gifts|gives|gl|glass|gle|global|globo|gm|gmail|gmo|gmx|gn|google|gop|gov|gp|gq|gr|graphics|gratis|green|gripe|gs|gt|gu|guide|guitars|guru|gw|gy|hamburg|haus|healthcare|help|here|hiphop|hiv|hk|hm|hn|holdings|holiday|homes|horse|host|hosting|house|how|hr|ht|hu|ibm|id|ie|il|im|immo|immobilien|in|industries|info|ing|ink|institute|insure|int|international|investments|io|iq|ir|is|it|je|jetzt|jm|jo|jobs|joburg|jp|juegos|kaufen|ke|kg|kh|ki|kim|kitchen|kiwi|km|kn|koeln|kp|kr|krd|kred|kw|ky|kz|la|lacaixa|land|lawyer|lb|lc|lds|lease|legal|lgbt|li|life|lighting|limited|limo|link|lk|loans|london|lotto|lr|ls|lt|ltda|lu|luxe|luxury|lv|ly|ma|madrid|maison|management|mango|market|marketing|mc|md|me|media|meet|melbourne|meme|memorial|menu|mg|mh|miami|mil|mini|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mobi|moda|moe|monash|money|mormon|mortgage|moscow|motorcycles|mov|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|nagoya|name|navy|nc|ne|net|network|neustar|new|nexus|nf|ng|ngo|nhk|ni|ninja|nl|no|np|nr|nra|nrw|nu|nyc|nz|okinawa|om|ong|onl|ooo|org|organic|otsuka|ovh|pa|paris|partners|parts|party|pe|pf|pg|ph|pharmacy|photo|photography|photos|physio|pics|pictures|pink|pizza|pk|pl|place|plumbing|pm|pn|pohl|poker|post|pr|praxi|press|pro|prod|productions|prof|properties|property|ps|pt|pub|pw|py|qa|qpon|quebec|re|realtor|recipes|red|rehab|reise|reisen|reit|ren|rentals|repair|report|republican|rest|restaurant|reviews|rich|rio|rip|ro|rocks|rodeo|rs|rsvp|ru|ruhr|rw|ryukyu|sa|saarland|sarl|sb|sc|sca|scb|schmidt|schule|science|scot|sd|se|services|sexy|sg|sh|shiksha|shoes|si|singles|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|social|software|sohu|solar|solutions|soy|space|spiegel|sr|st|su|supplies|supply|support|surf|surgery|suzuki|sv|sx|sy|sydney|systems|sz|taipei|tatar|tattoo|tax|tc|td|technology|tel|tf|tg|th|tienda|tips|tirol|tj|tk|tl|tm|tn|to|today|tokyo|tools|top|town|toys|tp|tr|trade|training|travel|tt|tui|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|university|uno|uol|us|uy|uz|va|vacations|vc|ve|vegas|ventures|versicherung|vet|vg|vi|viajes|villas|vision|vlaanderen|vn|vodka|vote|voting|voto|voyage|vu|wales|wang|watch|webcam|website|wed|wedding|wf|whoswho|wien|wiki|williamhill|wme|work|works|world|ws|wtc|wtf|xn--1qqw23a|xn--3bst00m|xn--3ds443g|xn--3e0b707e|xn--45brj9c|xn--45q11c|xn--4gbrim|xn--55qw42g|xn--55qx5d|xn--6frz82g|xn--6qq986b3xl|xn--80adxhks|xn--80ao21a|xn--80asehdb|xn--80aswg|xn--90a3ac|xn--c1avg|xn--cg4bki|xn--clchc0ea0b2g2a9gcd|xn--czr694b|xn--czru2d|xn--d1acj3b|xn--d1alf|xn--fiq228c5hs|xn--fiq64b|xn--fiqs8s|xn--fiqz9s|xn--flw351e|xn--fpcrj9c3d|xn--fzc2c9e2c|xn--gecrj9c|xn--h2brj9c|xn--i1b6b1a6a2e|xn--io0a7i|xn--j1amh|xn--j6w193g|xn--kprw13d|xn--kpry57d|xn--kput3i|xn--l1acc|xn--lgbbat1ad8j|xn--mgb9awbf|xn--mgba3a4f16a|xn--mgbaam7a8h|xn--mgbab2bd|xn--mgbayh7gpa|xn--mgbbh1a71e|xn--mgbc0a9azcg|xn--mgberp4a5d4ar|xn--mgbx4cd0ab|xn--ngbc5azd|xn--node|xn--nqv7f|xn--nqv7fs00ema|xn--o3cw4h|xn--ogbpf8fl|xn--p1acf|xn--p1ai|xn--pgbs0dh|xn--q9jyb4c|xn--qcka1pmc|xn--rhqv96g|xn--s9brj9c|xn--ses554g|xn--unup4y|xn--vermgensberater-ctb|xn--vermgensberatung-pwb|xn--vhquv|xn--wgbh1c|xn--wgbl6a|xn--xhq521b|xn--xkc2al3hye2a|xn--xkc2dl3a5ee0h|xn--yfro4i67o|xn--ygbi2ammx|xn--zfr164b|xxx|xyz|yachts|yandex|ye|yoga|yokohama|youtube|yt|za|zip|zm|zone|zw))$/i.test(v)
}],
```

I know it's not elegant, but it might help somebody out there, so I post it anyway.

Comment: I added a couple of domains like `mac` and `art` but otherwise a good solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend the prototype validations to create a custom one. Code:

```
Validation.add('validate-email', 'Please enter a valid Gmail address. For example johndoe@gmail.com.', function(v) { return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /^([a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]*@gmail.com)$/i.test(v) })
```

Guide [here](https://inchoo.net/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/).

Comment: So you suggest that I should include the complete list of valid domains in prototype validation?

Comment: based on your requirements you can do

Comment: Can you post a code example of that? An example with multiple domains, just like Zend validation requires? Because right now, it seems that prototype accepts email and after order completion, Zend declines it.

Comment: follow the inchoo guide (as mentioned on answer)

Comment: Can I just remove the Zend validation?

Comment: it will give error for other validation